# Computing multiple dask.dataframe.from_delayed() from one source

Tags: python, dask, dask-delayed, dask-dataframe

How can I compute `.from_delayed()` in parallel from one sequence of *delayed*?

```py
def foo():
    df1, df2 = ...  # prepare two pd.DataFrame() in one foo() call
    return df1, df2

dds = [dask.delayed(foo)() for _ in range(5)]  # 5 delayed pairs (df1, df2)...
df1 = dd.from_delayed([d[0] for d in dds], meta=...)
df2 = dd.from_delayed([d[1] for d in dds], meta=...)
client.compute([
    df1.to_parquet(file1, write_index=True, engine='fastparquet', compute=False),
    df2.to_parquet(file2, write_index=True, engine='fastparquet', compute=False)
], sync=True)
```

Here `foo()` will be called **10** times. Is it possible to create graph so it will be called only **5** times?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the clear example.  In principle you're correct that `foo` should only be called five times.  My guess is that optimizations are misbehaving here.  Short term I recommend trying the following from a recent release:

```
dask.config.set({"optimization.fuse.active": False})

... your code follows
```